# Load XML into grid view

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

Is it possible to bind the contents of an xml file with a data grid view in c#? Maybe using... LINQ? can I do that? I want to display the contents of an xml file within a grid view, edit, add or delete them there and then save them in the xml file I loaded in the first place.  I'd also like to be able to search through the grid and edit multiple items. I am creating a forms application.  The xml file is simple it only:

```
<people> 
    <person name='John' email='John@email.com'/>
</people>
```

There can be lots of records of type person.
What's the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: I want to develop the GUI in Winforms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way recommended by MSDN here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163669.aspx is to load it into a data set.

There is an entire set of code in Vb.Net over at DevX here and a tutorial that might help you with binding DataGridView to XML via data sets. [http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/28678/1954](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/28678)

Hope this helps. It is in Vb.Net but you will get idea.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have loaded your xml into "doc" XDocument

```
var persons = from item in doc.Descendants("person")
              select new
              {
                  Name = item.Element("name").Value,
                  Mail = item.Element("email").Value
              };

myDataboundControl.DataSource = persons;
myDataboundControl.Databind();
```

Comment: But that does not save the edits in the xml file. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

first you have to get the path of the XML file .Then create a new data set then bind the data set with the data grid view as your wish. you can also use SQL query to update,delete the XML file.

```
{ 
     Data Set dd = new Data Set();
    dd.ReadXml ("XML Path");
     DataTable xm = ds.Tables[0];
}
```